# How to enable identity insert on EF - code first context.Seed() and then disable again once data has been seeded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a bunch of records that need to be added to a SQL the database, these Ids will never change in their entire lifetime. i am using the seed override to insert my data and i need the IDs to match what i have specified. but once the seed function runs the Ids do not match what i have specified.

I do not want to permanently disable the identity inserts, i only want to disable the identity inserts during the seeding of my data and once the seeding has been completed SQL identity should take over again.

I have created a context initializer as follows

```
 public class EntitiesContextInitializer : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DB>
{
    public EntitiesContextInitializer()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DB context)
    {
        context.Setting.AddOrUpdate(
            new Setting
            {
                Id = 100,
                Name = "Setting 1"
            },
            new Setting
            {
                Id = 200,
                Name = "Setting 2"
            });

        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Once the above seeding has run, the sql record has the ID of 1 and not 100.

I have seen that you can disable the identity inserts within the onModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>().Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

But how would i switch it back on once the seeding has run?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Settings ON");
context.SaveChanges();
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Settings OFF");
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i did try that approach as well and Ids are still being assigned by SQL and not what i have specified.